# can we store the result of dynamic query into a variable and use it in if block?

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
Declare
v_count number 
v_sql varchar2(1000);

begin 

v_count :='select count(*) from table_name';

 Execute Immediate v_count;

if(v_count <>0) then 

v_sql :='delete table_name where x=X' ;

Execute Immediate v_sql ;

End if ;

end;
```

The task is we have to use dynamic queries to hit the tables .will the above query work?
it was giving me some typecasting errors..

Or is there any alternate way to store the result of the Dynamic sql query

Comment: Look at the doc (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BHCEBBAI) In particular the "RETURNING INTO" clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Declare
v_statement varchar2(32767);
v_count number; 
v_sql varchar2(1000);

begin 

 v_statement :='select count(*) from table_name';

 Execute Immediate l_statement into v_count;

  if v_count >0 then 
   ...
  end if ;

end;
```